# Редактор исходных кодов с встроенной кастомной системой документации

Tags: ide, документация, редактор, поиск-программ

Существуют ли редакторы исходных кодов под популярные языки программирования в которых есть возможность создавать свою собственную документацию? Ну например, написал класс или функцию и создал справку по ним, а потом при их использовании по нажатию F1 получил эту справку.

Comment: вроде всякие `*doc` в большинстве IDE поддерживаются

Comment: @Grundy могу ошибаться, но насколько я понимаю это система разниться от используемого языка. пока нашел Doxygen. осталось только редактор под него подобрать

Comment: скорее от используемой ide

Comment: можно пойти другим путем - писать так, что бы не приходилось часто смотреть документацию,